# Is there a method to print/debug from within a C function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, c

When you're extending [PostgreSQL in C](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html), how does one introspect/debug/dump a variable? Is there a method other than returning a custom result set to the client? Something like a `printf` that I can receive in a log on the server, or on the client?

Comment: You might also want to look at [ereport](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/error-message-reporting.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few methods for this documented in PostgreSQL in the documetnation page for [Error-log reporting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/error-message-reporting.html) there is the older method `elog`, and the newer method `ereport`

- `elog(level, "format string", ...);`
- `ereport(level, errmsg_internal("format string", ...));`

The `level` can be set to `ERROR`, `WARNING`, and `NOTICE` where `ERROR` aborts execution.

The guidance on them is

> Therefore, `elog` should be used only for internal errors and low-level debug logging. Any message that is likely to be of interest to ordinary users should go through `ereport`. Nonetheless, there are enough internal “cannot happen” error checks in the system that `elog` is still widely used; it is preferred for those messages for its notational simplicity.

There is far more information on "auxiliary routines" for ereport which allows you to specify `errcode`, `errmsg` (and plural), `errmsg_internal`, `errdetail` (and plural), `errdetail_internal`, `errdetail_log` (and plural), `errhint` (and plural), `errcontext`, `errposition`, `errtable`, `errtablecol`, `errtableconstraint`, `errdatatype`, `errdomainconstraint`, `errcode_for_file_access`, `errcode_for_socket_access`, `errhidestmt`, and `errhidecontext`.

---

You can also simply use

```
printf("Hello World! %d", myInt);
```

And you'll see the result in your server log,

```
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to elog rather than printf.  That way you get all the features of the logging system for free.

```
elog(NOTICE, "Hello World! %d", myInt);
```

Rather than NOTICE, you can use INFO, LOG, WARN, DEBUG1, etc.